# Null character(s) ignored enabled by default

Tags: c, stack, warnings

I am trying to implement a stack with an array! Every time I execute the program, it runs fine, but I am getting a warning as *null character(s) ignored enabled by default*.

What does this warning mean? What am I doing wrong?

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

# define MAX 10

int top = -1;
int arr[MAX];

void push(int item)
{
    if(top == MAX-1)
    {
        printf("Oops, stack overflow:\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    top = top + 1;
    arr[top] = item;
} // Warning

int popStack()
{
    if(top == 0)
    {
        printf("Stack already empty:\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int x = arr[top];
    top = top - 1;
    return x;
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=top; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int peek()
{
    if(top == -1)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty stack");
        exit(1);
    }
    return arr[top];
}

int main()
{
     int i, value;
     printf(" \n1. Push to stack");
     printf(" \n2. Pop from Stack");
     printf(" \n3. Display data of Stack");
     printf(" \n4. Display Top");
     printf(" \n5. Quit\n");
     while(1)
     {
          printf(" \nChoose option: ");
          scanf("%d", &i);
          switch(i)
          {
               case 1:
               {
                   int value;
                   printf("\nEnter a value to push into the stack: ");
                   scanf("%d", &value);
                   push(value);
                   break;
               }

               case 2:
               {
                    int p = popStack();
                    printf("Element popped out is:%d\n", p);
                    break;
               }

               case 3:
               {
                    printf("The elements are:\n");
                    display();
                    break;
               }

               case 4:
               {
                    int p = peek();
                    printf("The top position is: %d\n", p);
                    break;
               }

               case 5:
               {
                    exit(0);
               }

               default:
               {
                    printf("\nWrong choice for operation");
               }
         }
    }
    return 0;
} // Warning
```

I am using the [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) IDE.

Comment: When you say "I am using Dev C compiler", do you mean that you are using the Dev-C++ IDE? That comes with MinGW (gcc and g++ for compilers).

Comment: does the warning have a line associated with it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Somewhere in your source code file you have a character with the byte value 0 (the [ASCII NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character). Which will be invisible in most text editors.

The compiler (GCC) is just telling you that it ignored that character—which really shouldn't be there in your source code.

You could open your file in a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor), figure out where that character is and fix it, or delete your source file and copy-paste it back from the code you posted here.

Answer (score 21):

If you are seeing large numbers of these null character warnings, consider the following as a possibility. The problem could be caused by someone creating the source file using an editor that saved the file as [16-bit Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

To fix that (on Linux), a hex editor is needed. Simply open up the file in the [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) editor (other editors may also support this too) check the File Properties to see the encoding, if it is a [UTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)/[UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) 16 then in the *Document* menu you can change it to UTF8. It's probably worth removing the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if there is one as well.

In this case the error is to be expected because a UCS16 encoding of characters in the ASCII range will make every second byte a null character.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, the warning means there are null bytes in your source code.

This can happen, for example, when you attempt to compile code in Linux that was originally written as a Visual Studio project in Windows, which by default saves as UTF-16. Since g++ expects source files to be in UTF-8, it ends up reading null bytes.

In my case, the easiest solution was to convert the encoding using iconv (Linux)

```
iconv myfile -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 > myfile
```

You can check a file's encoding with file

```
file myfile
```