# Library encoded differently than self written program - stray char error

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors

I have a problem including a library to my C++ project. The library is written by collegues but when I try to include it in my project I get a whole bunch of `error: stray character in program`, namely these:

```
||=== Build: Debug in WindowsDgps (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\220' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\3' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\4' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\377' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\377' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\270' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '@' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\200' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\16' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\37' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\272' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\16' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\264' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\315' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\270' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\1' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|1|error: stray '\315' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\1' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\272' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\340' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\16' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '#' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\1' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\2' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\26' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\7' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\10' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '`' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\220' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\7' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\24' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\2' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\4' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\1' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\4' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\4' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\375' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\27' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\3' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\20' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\260' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\10' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\17' in program|
..\WindowsAPI\VibroTacLib.dll|3|error: stray '\5' in program|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 35 warning(s) (4 minute(s), 50 second(s)) ===|
```

I figure this is because the library is encoded in a different way than my project, after finding several similar questions that had this error inside of the self written program. Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem? 
Maybe I included the library wrongly, I use Code::Blocks software and clicked "Build options" on my project, and in the Linker settings tab I included `..\WindowsAPI\libVibroTacLib.a` in the Link libraries window.
The `#include` part in my `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "VibroTac.h"
#include "errorcodes.h"
#include "vibroTacTypeDef.h"
#include "VibroTacLib.dll"
```

Comment: Maybe this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/17222397/1741542. The second answer suggests the files encoded in some 16bit Unicode.

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/q/19149060/1741542

Comment: @Olaf thank you for that. Though I don't quite understand what file I have to open because I cannot open a .dll file, can I? I tried with PSPadEditor...

Comment: *If* the source file is encoded in UTF-16, every character occupies two bytes instead of one. This would explain the "warning: null character(s) ignored".

Comment: A DLL is not a source code file to be compiled. It's the end product. Don't try to compile the DLL.

Comment: I overlooked your final `#include "VibroTacLib.dll"`. This is explained in the second question, I mentioned. Remove this line, and you might be done.

Comment: @Olaf when I remove the mentioned line the problem is, that the functions I call are not implemented...At least I get this error code from `errorcodes.h`. That is why I thought I would have to include the .dll as well...

Comment: Nevertheless, keep the line removed. When you get other error messages, you must figure out, what to include. Search for the missing function/method/variable names in the header files `*.h` and include these.

Comment: Sorry to ask another stupid question @Olaf, but do you know how I should include these missing functions? For example the `vibroTac.connect()` looks like this in the `*.h` file: `virtual int CALL connect(const char* port);`. Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: I can't tell, because I don't know this vibrotac library. If this method is already in the library, you must add it to the list of libraries used by your program. If this is a method supposed to be implemented by a derived class, you must create a new class inheriting from the base class, see [virtual function specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) for a simple example.

Comment: @Olaf thank you for your help. It turned out the author of this library capsulatet its functionality. With another way to call the functions it works.